# Invalid type for parameter Message

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I try to use "signal" in Django to send SNS email in AWS and my code is:

```
import boto3
from properties.models import PropertyList
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=PropertyList)
def send_property_details(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        sns = boto3.client('sns')

        response = sns.publish(
            TopicArn='',# I write value of TopicArn
            Message={
            "name": instance.title,
            "description": instance.description
                },
            MessageStructure='json',
            Subject='New Property Created',
            MessageAttributes={
                'default':{
                    'DataType':'String',
                    'StringValue':instance.title
                    }
                },
            )

        print(response['MessageId'])
```

I get error as:

> Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter Message,
>   value: {'name': 'aws', 'description': 'test'}, type: ,
>   valid types:

In AWS docs said If I want to send different messages for each transport protocol, set the value of the `MessageStructure` parameter to JSON and use a JSON object for the Message parameter. What is wrong in my code?

**Note**: I want to send more than values so I need to send JSON

Answer (score 5):

In the example you paste the Message is a dictionary. That may be the reason for the error. Try to modify Message as follows:

```
import boto3, json    
...

mesg = json.dumps({
    "default": "defaultfield", # added this 
    "name": instance.title,
    "description": instance.description
})
response = sns.publish(
    TopicArn='topicARNvalue',
    Message=mesg,
    MessageStructure='json',
    Subject='New Property Created',
    MessageAttributes={}
)
```

Comment: I get this error 
An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Publish operation: Invalid parameter: Message Structure - No default entry in JSON message body

Comment: Following the error, I update the post, it seems that the json object needs a `'default'`field. Have also a look at [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/262).

Comment: when I do that all I get in email , this defaultfield,  value of default,
when I make messageStructure = String I get full msg but as json
"{"name":"aws", "description":"test"}" like this